# NFS server export list empty

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

After upgrading my router, I am unable to mount NFS shares from a Debian server on an OS X client. I have updated `/etc/exports` according to the new IP address of the client (first line previously worked with the old IP, second is a MWE):

```
/mnt/backup  192.168.3.3/255.255.255.0(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
/mnt/backup  *(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

I've applied the changes with

```
exportfs -ar
```

And have also restarted the daemons:

```
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
/etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
```

All with no errors. `showmount -e` on the server returns an empty list and I am unable to mount the share from the OS X client. `rpcinfo -p` shows versions 2-4 of NFS, and `nfsstat –s` has an entry for "Server nfs v3". Any ideas?

Comment: iptables? can you mount the volume on the localhost?

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying the same mount point on multiple lines.  If you need to define multiple clients with different options you should use a space separated list.

Comment: After leaving the machine overnight, `showmount` now lists the partition, and it is mountable. Strange... but at least now it's working... Thanks for the tip about mountpoints defined on multiple lines @yoonix